# my android app crashes after 8 activities,what should i do?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am doing a QCM and there is 20 questions,20 activity and every single one have a question and a button to get to the next one but the problem is when it reaches the 8th activity it crashes, Even I add `android:noHistory="true"`

```
  public class qc8 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  Button b1;
  RadioGroup r;

  TextView countdown;


   private void nextacti(){
       Intent i1 = new Intent(this,qc9.class);
        this.startActivity(i1);
   }
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.qc8);
    b1 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.suivant18);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    countdown = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.countdo8);
    r=(RadioGroup)this.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup18);
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
           countdown.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished /        1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            nextacti();
        }
     }.start();

}        

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(r.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
    case R.id.radio08:qc1.scor++;break;
    }

    nextacti();
  }

 }
```

the Logcat: 03-26 12:55:45.795: W/ResourceType(10849): Failure getting entry for 0x0108096d (t=7 e=2413) in package 0 (error -75) 03-26 12:55:46.195: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10849): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length 03-26 12:55:46.195: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10849): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length 03-26 12:55:46.615: D/GestureDetector(10849): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0 03-26 12:55:47.395: D/GestureDetector(10849): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0 03-26 12:55:47.460: W/ResourceType(10849): Failure getting entry for 0x0108096d (t=7 e=2413) in package 0 (error -75) 03-26 12:55:47.695: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10849): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length 03-26 12:55:47.695: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10849): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length 03-26 12:55:48.445: D/GestureDetector(10849): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 4 mFalseSizeCnt:0 03-26 12:55:48.895: D/GestureDetector(10849): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0 03-26 12:55:49.155: W/ResourceType(10849): Failure getting entry for 0x0108096d (t=7 e=2413) in package 0 (error -75) 03-26 12:55:49.370: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10849): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length 03-26 12:55:49.370: E/SpannableStringBuilder(10849): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length 03-26 12:55:49.945: D/GestureDetector(10849): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0 03-26 12:55:50.465: D/GestureDetector(10849): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0 03-26 12:55:50.555: W/ResourceType(10849): Failure getting entry for 0x0108096d (t=7 e=2413) in package 0 (error -75) 03-26 12:55:50.585: D/AndroidRuntime(10849): Shutting down VM 03-26 12:55:50.585: W/dalvikvm(10849): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41505930) 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ilearn/com.example.ilearn.qc9}: java.lang.NullPointerException 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299) 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154) 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284) 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306) 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): at com.example.ilearn.qc9.onCreate(qc9.java:28) 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255) 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097) 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213) 03-26 12:55:50.610: E/AndroidRuntime(10849): ... 11 more

Comment: please post logcat and your 8th activity code.

Comment: what is exception past log

Comment: You register each activity in manifest file?

Comment: Kindly paste the code of that corresponding activity.

Comment: Try to add onResume(),onDistroy() methods in each activity

Comment: Why have a separate `Activity` for each question? Just use a single `Activity` and change the question.

Answer (score 0):

**App crashes after 8 activities,what should i do?**

There may be the following reasons for the app to crash:

```
1. You may have not registered your 9th activity in your manifest.
2. Check the id for the button in your 8th activity.
```

Please let me know if it works and also post the logcat details as it is the actual friend of a developer which lets us aware of the problem.. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like android crashes after 8 activities. The reason for this could be that U made some mistake in the activity that crashes the app. 
Check the button id in your 8th activity if you copy pasted it and if there is another instance named with the same id, this could happen.

Also from your logcat view "NullPointerException" is present, check for proper initialization of object.

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(10849): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(10849): at com.example.ilearn.qc9.onCreate(qc9.java:28)

Whatever is on line 28 is an object which is null and you are trying to use it. My best guess is that `b1` is the object that's null and this line `b1.setOnClickListener(this);` is trying to use it.

Comment: thanks the problem was from the button as u said bro.